# How to iframe part of webpage from server A to server B?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a web page from server A, I want to only `<iframe>` the form on it to server B. 
The form resides on the top right corner of this web page, `width: 252px; height: 436px;` 
Is this JavaScript can do it? or just simple HTML and CSS work?

For example, I put this script on server B, it will show top left corner of  webpage: http://www.example.com/example.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/example.html" scrolling="no" width="252" height="436"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not possible without fetching the resources on server side

Comment: Hello Pekka, I have access on server B

Answer (score 3):

iframes are a way of embedding the entirety of some other webpage within the body of the current page. The frame is part of the 'host' document, while the content it's loading is a completely separate document. It's no different than having two separate browser windows open.

If server B cannot be told to serve up only the form you want, then you cannot use an iframe to display just the form. You'll just get the entire page. You'd have to fetch the page separately, extract the relevant bits of HTML, and insert just that snippet.

This can also not be done via javascript, as you'd be attempting to load a resource from another page, running into the same-origin security policies.

Comment: +1 to clarify what @Marc means by "fetch the page separately": Using a server-side language like PHP or Perl. Server-side access does not have the single origin restrictions of JavaScript. However, the resulting HTML will not be running in the context of Server A any more. It will behave like HTML code served by Server B. Any validation JavaScript bound to the form, for example, is likely to break.

Comment: Hello Marc,maybe i was not clear, what i am trying to do is very simple, like this http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=108520     I just want to show the top right corner of a web page, but the CSS seems doesn't work well. I don't know how to cut exactly the part I want...

Comment: @peipei: you cannot have CSS from server A affect anything in the page that was loaded into the iframe from server B. they're two completely independent pages. You COULD use some javascript to tell the iframe what position to scroll to, but that's highly unreliable and dependent on how the user's browser is rendering the pages.